# MFMailComposer not Opening in iOS9 with XCode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I am using MFMailComposer in my iOS 8 application but after updating my Xcode to XCode 7 and iOS to iOS 9 it stopped working and automatically closed. I tried on iOS Simulator and real device also but having the same problem.

Is any has the solution for that?

Comment: it is issue in Xcode 7 but it is open in actual device. And plz post code.

Comment: Post the implementation.

Comment: Works fine for me, post your code.

Comment: @ekant use this condition if(youmailcomposerObject){//present viewcontroller code}; and run your device in real device and add account in your device.

Comment: Thanks. it resolved on Device after adding the mail account.
But it's still a bug on iOS 9 Simulator.

Comment: It is still a bug in the simulator, with Xcode 7.0.1.
It now reports that the mail composition service "exited unexpectedly".